# How to create fire flames in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am new to Android application development. I am just trying to create a application with fire flames.How to create fire flames in Android dynamically.For Example, if i touch the screen, fire should move.Please let me know steps or any link where can i refer.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think `OpenGL` is your best option if you want to make complex animations at run time, although it's not that straight forward to learn.

Please take a look at [this link](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/376/android-ui-making-a-live-wallpaper-fire-simulation/) as it seems to be what you are looking for (I haven't tested it).

If you have checked the link, got the idea and still want to embark on this new adventure, you can take a look at the [official Android OpenGL docs](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html), they are a good place to get familiar with `Open GL`. Also, [this](http://www.learnopengles.com/) seems to be a good `OpenGL` tutorial to get deeper into graphics development.